# Symfony, The receiver "scheduler_default" does not exist

Tags: symfony, symfony-scheduler

```
php bin/console messenger:consume -vv scheduler_default


In ConsumeMessagesCommand.php line 168:

[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]
The receiver "scheduler_default" does not exist.
```

I have followed the steps to create a scheduler and consume messages as schedules, my scheduler is not being identified as a scheduler even though I have used the correct Attribute and have implemented the ScheduleProviderInterface.

[Following this official documentaion](https://symfony.com/doc/current/scheduler.html#consuming-messages-running-the-worker), according to this I have to consume message as scheduler_ followed by the AsSchedule attribute name. But it says the receiver does not exist.

Php bin/console debug:scheduler says "No schedules found"

```
Scheduler
=========


 [ERROR] No schedules found.
```

Here is my Schedule.php file

```
// src/Scheduler/Schedule.php
namespace App\Scheduler;

use Symfony\Component\Scheduler\RecurringMessage;
use Symfony\Component\Scheduler\Schedule;
use Symfony\Component\Scheduler\ScheduleProviderInterface;
use App\Message\Foo;

#[AsSchedule('default')]
class DefaultScheduleProvider implements ScheduleProviderInterface
{
    public function getSchedule(): Schedule
    {  
        $schedule = new Schedule();
        $schedule->add(RecurringMessage::every('2 days', new Foo()));
        return $schedule;
    }
}
```

Config
packages/messenger.yaml

```
framework:
    messenger:
        # Uncomment this (and the failed transport below) to send failed messages to this transport for later handling.
        # failure_transport: failed

        transports:
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#transport-configuration
            # async: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'
            # failed: 'doctrine://default?queue_name=failed'
            # sync: 'sync://'

        routing:
            # Route your messages to the transports
            # 'App\Message\YourMessage': async
```

I'm not sure where its going wrong, I just want to set a basic scheduler for doing tasks periodically.